# handle multiselect case on selecting and deselecting button/component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to to achieve something here, I this multi select buttons I am trying to set multi select using custom component, but here I need to make one validation that at least one should be selected under this. Like it should behave like atleat one should be selected.
It can select multiple, but when last one is selected then it should remain selected.
with message saying that at least one required to be selected.

Example - If multiple is selected, then file no error(like below);

[image]

But when there's only one selected and then user try to deselect it, then it should show message something like this....(like below)

[image]

In this case, there's should be one message below it, `"Atleast one should be selected.."`

https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-haze-7f214

this is the sandbox link where I am tying to acheeve it.
(Also, I am using reduxform, and this is custom field component I am trying to build with custom validation)

Comment: I think you need t use react state and avoid using dom changes like toggleClass. If you rewrite it to controllable by react way you'll add such thing easily)

Comment: @boikov can you help me here, just new to React concept

Comment: @boikov Could you please help me here..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Component code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Avatar } from "antd";
const weekDays = ["S", "M", "T", "W", "TH", "F", "ST"];

export default function App() {
  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState({});
  const [error, setError] = useState();
  const handleSelect = (day) => {
    if(error) {
      setError(null);
    }
    const newSelectedDays = { ...selectedDays, [day]: !selectedDays[day] };
    if(!Object.values(newSelectedDays).find(x => x)) {
      setError('Atleast one should be selected..')
      return;
    }
    setSelectedDays(newSelectedDays);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {weekDays.map((day) => (
        <Avatar
          onClick={() => handleSelect(day)}
          className={`week-day ${selectedDays[day] ? "selected-day" : ""}`}
          key={day}
        >
          {day}
        </Avatar>
      ))}
      {error}
    </div>
  );
}
```

styles code

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.week-day {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 1rem 1.1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin: 0.2rem;
  margin-top: 3rem;
  color: black;
}

.selected-day {
  background: magenta;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: What if I want to select monday by default at very start?

Comment: You can add default value `  const [selectedDays, setSelectedDays] = useState({'M': true});
`